# Submitting a podcast to Apple results in "Can't read your feed"

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I have a podcast that works in iTunes, but when I submit it to the iTunes store via podcastsconnect.apple.com, I receive "Validation failed" together with "Can't read your feed". It works when I open it directly in iTunes, and it appears to be a [valid feed](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.trinitychurchbradford.org.uk%2Fsermons%2Fpodcasts%2Fpodcast.xml). Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Pretty sure this is SSL related. Still debugging - I'll post an answer if ever I figure it out.

Comment: AFAIK Apple's server side podcast client implementation is Java-based. Again AFAIK Java does not support strong TLS crypto. Test your website with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Comment: Ah - thanks @MaxRied! I suspect the problem is this: *Java 6u45: Client does not support DH parameters > 1024 bits*. I'll try reducing the number of bits in my DH setup. I also discovered I'm vulnerable to Poodle and get a C - last I checked it was A+, so I must have messed something up.

Comment: Tell me if this worked, I write an answer then.

Comment: Not yet, sadly. I've switched to a 1024 bit DH key, but still no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the iTunes Store doesn't support certificates from Let's Encrypt, after discussion with Apple Support.